# How to insert data from textbox and date/time into Access database?

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to insert values into a locally hosted access database but I believe I'm passing the wrong values for Access.

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tracker(INum,IName,IVio,IDate,ISanc,ITodayDate,IGnG) values('" + txtNumber + "','" + txtName + "','" + txtVio + "','" + calDate + "','" + txtSan + "', '" + calTodayDate + "','" + txtGnG + "')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Can anyone tell me what I could be doing wrong? This is going into a submit button.
Error: [http://screencast.com/t/yynPsrs5][1]

I've added an image showing the error.

- Box 1: Number
- Box 2 & 3: Text
- Box 4: Short Date (1/1/2001)
- Box 5: Text
- Box 6: Short Date (1/1/2001)
- Box 7: Text

According to the error there is an issue at line 40, this is what I have at line 40; command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Can't determine, are you getting an error? You should be using parameterized queries, not only does it save you from SQL injection attacks, but it helps format the data correctly for the data type. Its a good habit to get into, even if this app will never run outside your personal PC.

Comment: Do your datetime columns accept the value you get from calendar input?

Comment: do a google search on how to construct an Insert statement into AccessDatabase.. also wrap the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` method around a try{}catch{} and trap the exception.meassage..

Comment: you don't need to enclose `number` values in `''`, double quotes are enough. If `INum` is of type number or integer, you need `" + txtNumber + ",`, not `'" + txtNumber + "',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tracker(INum,IName,IVio,IDate,ISanc,ITodayDate,IGnG) values(@txtNumber,@txtName,@txtVio,@calDate,@txtSan,@calTodayDate,@txtGnG)";
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@txtNumber", txtNumber);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@txtName", txtName);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@txtVio", txtVio);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@calDate", calDate);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@txtSan", txtSan);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@calTodayDate", calTodayDate);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@txtGnG", txtGnG);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Make sure that all the values are on the right type before running the query.